# How can I clean up my code? It's in a dictionary and the things I try to remove, are not recognized to be in the dictionary

Tags: python

How could I clean up my code? I have the answer that the program wants but since this is zybooks, it want's the answer to be exact but my code outputs for example ('hello', 1) and the output that I need is hello 1. Is there anything I can do?

Question from assignment:
Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the file using the csv.reader() method. The file contains a list of words separated by commas. Your program should output the words and their frequencies (the number of times each word appears in the file) without any duplicates.

My code:

```
import csv
count = {}
inputfile = input('')
with open(inputfile, 'r') as file:  
    file = csv.reader(file)
    for row in file:
        for words in row:
            if words not in count.keys():
                count[words] = 1
            else:
                count[words] += 1
    dictionary_items = count.items()
    for item in dictionary_items:
        print(item)
```

Things I tried:
I tried like using the built in function .pop() but it wouldn't let me do anything because it did not recognize the '(', " ' ", ',', ')' as something in the dictionary.

My output:

```
('hello', 1)
('cat', 2)
('man', 2)
('hey', 2)
('dog', 2)
('boy', 2)
('Hello', 1)
('woman', 1)
('Cat', 1)
```

Output I need:

```
hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 2
Hello 1
woman 1
Cat 1
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for your assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Loop over `count.items()`

Instead of using `dictionary_items` and looping over each (*key*, *value*) tuple in the dictionary, you can directly loop over the dictionary like this:

```py
for word, num_occurrences in count.items():
    print(word, num_occurrences)
```

#### Option 2: Use unpacking operator

Change `print(item)` to `print(*item)`.

In this case, this uses the [unpacking operator (`*`)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). In this instance, the operator unpacks the `item` tuple and passes each item in the tuple as a separate argument to `print()`, in order.

Since the default separator between arguments to `print()` is a space in the printed output, the `print()` function will automatically insert a space between the first item and the second item in the tuple in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is because *dictionary_items* in your code is a list of tuple of dictionary items.

For eg lets look at a dictionary:

```
car = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
```

when you use .items(), `x = car.items()`

Output will be:

```
dict_items([('brand', 'Ford'), ('model', 'Mustang'), ('year', 1964)])
```

One way to solve is problem is not saving your answers in dictionary.

Comment: To be pedantic, [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), not a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).